# Erro ao executar projeto Xamarin no visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

Quando tento executar o meu projeto `Xaramin` é reportado o seguinte ***erro***:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Column  Suppression State
>   Error     Exception while loading assemblies:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly
>   'System.Collections.NonGeneric, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono
>   for Android profile? Nome do arquivo:
>   'System.Collections.NonGeneric.dll'    em
>   Xamarin.Android.Tuner.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference
>   reference, ReaderParameters parameters)    em
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(ICollection`1
>   assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)    em
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute() SojaaApp.Droid

Comment: Erikson, quando dá o erro? Em que tipo de projeto? Android? Forms? iOS? Windows Forms? 
Você está usando alguma dll de terceiros referenciada via NuGet?

Comment: Quando tento executar o projeto na minha máquina virtual ou smartphone, o projeto é Blank App Universal Windows . Estou usando a dll do mongodb.